# Can't get past EFI to install RHEL on HP Itanium Server

Tags: linux, rhel, boot, system-installation, uefi

When I am trying to install RHEL (6.3, 5.8, 4.8) on an HP Integrity Server rx2660 Itanium with 4GB RAM, I keep getting to the same point which is

```
Loading file efi\boot\initrd.img...done
```

After that nothing happens and I can’t continue installing RHEL.

Also, when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, I see the message

```
Unable to identify CD-ROM format
unable to load NLS charset utf8
```

and the SCSI CDROM fails to mount a CD/DVD.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have the correct hardware version. There is no Itanium version for RHEL6, so the RHEL6.3 you are using is almost certainly not the right version.

You want IA64 not amd64 or x86_64.

https://www.redhat.com/products/enterprise-linux/server/compare.html

Answer (score 0):

The fact that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> has the effect you described is a pretty strong sign that the Linux kernel has in fact successfully started up. But you might be bitten by the fact that these servers are most definitely not PCs. They have the VGA connector only because these servers can also run an Itanium version of Windows; if not for that, any PC-like KVM connections would be *optional*.

The rx2660 server might be configured to use a *serial console* by default. The EFI might output to both the VGA display and the serial port, but once the OS kernel boots, only the currently-configured console may get the installer output.

[image: Image of the rear of HPe RX2660]

In this picture, item #7 is the console serial port. Connect a null-modem cable to it and connect it to e.g. a laptop with a serial port or a USB-to-serial adapter. Configure the serial port to 9600 bps, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no parity. Have the laptop connected and running e.g. PuTTY in serial port mode (with the appropriate serial port selected) while powering up the server. If you see no output, press Enter on the laptop once or twice.

You should see the Management Processor (MP for short) login prompt: the factory default administrator login should be login "admin", password "Admin". If the MP administrator password is lost, power down the server, unplug all power cables for it for at least 30 seconds, then plug them back in and pay attention to the laptop connected to the serial console port. While the MP is resetting, it will display a prompt to reset MP to factory defaults by pressing a particular key *when prompted* on the serial console *only*.

Once you have successfully logged in to the MP, you can use the `HE` command to get help on MP commands. One of the first commands you might want to use is `LC` (Lan Configure) to configure the network parameters for the MP. You could then plug in a network cable (ideally connected to a secure management network only) to the iLO MP LAN port (item #6 in the picture). After that, you could connect to the iLO using SSH or a web browser, instead of using the serial port connection.

Other important commands in the MP are:

- `VFP`, displays the status of the front panel LEDs, diagnostic codes and other server status
- `CO`, connects through the MP to the actual server console. *Only in this mode you will see the output from the actual operating system, or from the OS installer.* To disconnect from the console mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.
- `CL`, Console Log, to view the past console output.
- `SL`, Show Logs, to display detailed hardware event logs.

It is very likely that once you can get to the MP console mode (either through the serial port or through the MP LAN connection), you will find that the Linux installer is prompting you on the console.

Note that unlike a VGA display, a serial port will normally send the display contents only once until the contents are changed: if the installer is already running when you access the `CO`nsole mode of the MP, you might need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to tell the OS/installer to refresh the current display.